# The same UI POV in all modes

Tags: interface

In Blender 3, each mode (Modelling, Geometry Nodes etc.) has its individual UI POV (or how the user sees the scene in the graphical interface, I do not know how it is called in Blender). For example, I change the view to the currently modified object, then I change the mode and Blender shows some other object which I do not edit at the moment.

Is this possible to have a unified POV for all modes? Or alternately, can I edit Geometry Nodes in the Modelling mode?

Comment: Hi :). These are called workspaces. They're just a predefined set of editors, which you can change. So yes, you can open a *Geometry Nodes Editor* in a *Modeling* workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DNR: Yes you can edit Geometry Nodes in the Modeling workspace.  No you can't sync the same editor in two different workspaces so that both workspaces always show the same thing.

The manual section [*Window System Introduction*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/introduction.html) is a good starting point for learning the names of the various parts of the Blender User Interface.

The simplest form of Blender has a single window that has a *Top Bar* that contains the various master menus and a collection of tabs for *Workspaces*.

To answer your first question, yes, you can change the layout of a given workspace.  A *Workspace* is subdivided into [*areas*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/areas.html). As you can see from the area manual section, you can change the layout; adding or removing areas, and moving the borders to make one area larger and another smaller.  You can even [*split*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/areas.html#splitting) an area into two new areas or *join* two areas into a single area.

You can put any editor you want into a workspace by selecting it from the *Editor Type* menu, so yes you can have a Geometry Node Editor in the same workspace as a 3D Viewport editor.

What you can't do, is have an instance of an editor in one workspace exactly match an instance of the same editor in another workspace.  The editor windows are separate from each other and (with the exception of the timeline indicator) there is no synchronizing.